# Does EntityFramework code-first works fine with Managed ODP.net provider for oracle?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, odp.net

We have build our application's data access layer using repository pattern and we are using Managed ODP.net provider to work with oracle data.
We are facing some problem while trying to make entity framework code-first work with oracle.

```
public class Repository<TObject>
            where TObject : class
{        
protected DbSet<TObject> DbSet
        {
            get
            {
                return Context.Set<TObject>();
            }
        }

public virtual TObject Create(TObject TObject)
        {
            var newEntry = DbSet.Add(TObject);

             return newEntry;
        }

...
}
```

Create function is not actually creating an entry into DB. Get function works fine though.

Any suggestions around this issue..?
Or, can anyone suggest whether it's good approach to follow ODP with entityframework code-first.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODP.NET managed data provider does not support code-first development with the Entity Framework. From its readme.txt in odp.net/doc under the oracle client dir:

"7.  ODP.NET 11.2.0.3 does not support Code First nor the DbContext APIs."

You'll have to use the model-first or database-first approach.